# Triple Boot (Windows 10, Ubuntu 16.04, OS X 10.11)

Tags: grub2, partitioning, 16.04, uefi, macosx

have a Lenovo Laptop, the ideapad z710, it has a

```
Intel Core i7-4710MQ
NVIDIA GeForce 840M/2GB
16GB Ram
1TB SSHD
```

and I want to install Ubuntu which I use as my main OS and beside that Windows 10 and OS X 10.11.

I already have my 3 bootable USB-Sticks and I want to know if I am doing this right.

First I boot my GParted Live USB and create a new partition-table. Then I create 5 partitions:

```
200MB fat32 efi Flag(Boot)
250GB hfs+ MAC
250GB ntfs WINDOWS
218GB ext4 LINUX
32GB swap
250GB ntfs ---> File Share for all 3 partitions
```

Then I start my OS X USB and Erase the MAC partition to a hfs+ Journaled. Next I install OS X to it. I install Windows on the WINDOWS partition and finally I am installing Ubuntu to the LINUX part. and the bootloader to the efi part.. If i than start my Notebook i come into GRUB which I like, but I can't boot my OS X from there. I can only boot it if I insert my USB and start it from there. What should I do that I can boot OS X from GRUB because I want to use it as my bootloader!

So now my questions:

```
Are my steps right?
What can I do that my GRUB is working right?
How can I share the last partition between all 3 OSes
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Booting OS X on non-Apple hardware constitutes a legal gray area, at best, in many parts of the world, and discussions of this matter are, if I'm not mistaken, off-topic here. You should ask about that on a Hackintosh forum. You'll need a special Hackintosh-specific boot loader, though; GRUB is unlikely to do a good job of booting OS X on non-Apple hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're lucky, I got myself a Lenovo laptop too, and did the exact same thing. It's not that hard; first you want to erase your disk and use the GPT partition table. You can do this quite easily with a gparted livecd, which can be downloaded from http://gparted.org. Create a partition table, and set the type to "gpt". After you've done that, start the Windows installer in UEFI mode from a USB drive. Install Windows as normally, but use a smaller partition from the start, in order to create a partition for Ubuntu/OS X later on the empty space. When you're done installing Windows, you can go on with installing Ubuntu. When Ubuntu starts asking where you want to install it, click "manually specify partitions", then click next. Now you have to create two partitions, one EXT4 partition, and one swap partition. For the size of the main partition, the EXT4, you can choose how big you want it to be yourself. Just keep in mind that OS X needs about 15GB to install, so just leave about 40GB and you're good. For the swap partition size: set it to 4096MB. (That's 4GB.) When Ubuntu is done installing, the default bootloader will be grub, if you've done everything correctly. Now boot up your OS X installer through Clover, just leave the other two operating systems it might detect alone. When OS X asks where to install, create a new partition on the beginning of the empty space. If it doesn't allow it, or it can't seem to find the empty space, boot up the gparted livecd again, and create an HFS+ partition yourself by right-clicking on the "unallocated" section, create, and select HFS+ as the filesystem. Boot up the OS X installer again, and tell it to install onto the newly through gparted created HFS+ partition. When it's done, use the Clover bootloader from the USB to boot up OS X. When it has booted, install Clover in legacy mode, and set your BIOS to legacy. You will be presented with the Clover bootloader afterwards. From here you can boot all three operating systems. Just one quick note: For Windows it might say "Operating System Not Found", just press a key to restart, it will boot fine. It just won't boot into legacy mode, because your Windows has been installed in UEFI mode. If you have any questions, let me know, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was really helpful
But why can't I user Clover in UEFI mode?

Comment: Well, for me it didn't work, as the computer somehow didn't want to boot anything else than Windows its standard .efi file. However, you can try the direct UEFI version of Clover, if you want. I know this works. And most of the time I'm like "If it ain't broke, don't fix it." But like I said, you could always try. If it doesn't work, reinstall Clover, and set it to legacy. Should do fine from there.

Comment: Hey @Chaos_, if you liked Gert's answer then you should accept it as the answer to your question, and also upvote it when you get 15 reputation points.  And welcome to AskUbuntu!

Comment: Thanks! I'd appreciate it. Also: I just read something about the Windows 10 Anniversary Update: The update might erase all other partitions on which it can detect different operating systems. So I'd say; be careful with Windows 10.